# Docker Swarm overlay network issue on Mac

Tags: macos, docker, docker-swarm, orchestration

I have two physical machines both running in the same network, and I made one of them a manager and the other one worker. The nodes join correctly and I was able to view them by running `docker node ls`.

In the docker yml file, I have 4 applications in total which two on them running on the manager node and others running on the worker node.

My issue is that the applications in the manager node cannot reach the applications in the worker node via the overlay network.

**More information:**

The manager node is running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and the worker node is running on a Mac mini(macOS 10.14.1). The architecture looks like the below:
[image]

I suspect this is a Mac issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you get confirmation on whether this is a known limitation of macos?

Comment: No, I could find anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to work around similar issues. The root cause is because Docker Desktop for MacOS is not a "true docker" and it does not forward network requests from/to other hosts properly. Details are here: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/

The work around is to use Virtual Machines in MacOS (e.g., VirtualBox) by `docker-machine` command lines. Details are introduced in [How to connect to a docker container from outside the host (same network) [OSX 10.11]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922007/how-to-connect-to-a-docker-container-from-outside-the-host-same-network-osx-1)

I have tried the VirtualBox path, adding a third Network Adapter with bridged mode, and I can finally ping 3 nodes from the container.